# Will SimpleImputer Fill Missing Values using metrics from the training or test set when we use a transformation pipeline on the test set?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am reading Aurélien Géron's Hands on machine Learning (page 79 for reference) and It is written in the book that when using a transformation pipeline on the test set, we should only use tranform instead of `fit_transform`.

My question is:

1. Are hyperparameters of the tranformers are actually tweeked when we are using `fit_transform`?
2. If yes, if for example we are using `SimpleImputer` on the training set to fill the missing values using the median, when we are transforming the test set, will the Imputer fill the missing values using the median of the training, or the test set? I think it would be more logical to use the median of the test set, so I think it would be more logical to use fit_transform on the test set. Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use fit_transform, the method first fits the data (i.e., learns the parameters of the transformation) and then transforms the data based on the learned parameters.

In the case of SimpleImputer, when you fit it on the training set, it learns the median of the training set. When you then transform the test set, it fills the missing values using the median of the training set, not the test set.

The reason for this is that you want to apply the same transformation to the test set that you applied to the training set. If you were to fit the imputer on the test set, it would learn the median of the test set, which could be different from the median of the training set. This would mean that you're applying a different transformation to the test set than you applied to the training set, which could lead to inconsistent results.

In general, you should avoid using fit_transform on the test set because it can lead to data leakage. Data leakage occurs when information from the test set is used to influence the model, which can lead to overly optimistic performance estimates. By only using transform on the test set, you ensure that the model is not influenced by any information from the test set.